# Approximate using DFT phase shifting property

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, dft

I have a discrete signal $x(n)$ having $N$ samples with DFT $X(n)$. Here $N$ is ***large*** say $N=600$. Let the samples of $x(n)$ be, $x(n) = \big[x(0), x(1), x(2), ..., x(N-1)\big]$. But if suppose instead of sampling at the zeroth instant, we began at $k^{th}$ instant, then the new DFT using phase shifting property will be:

$$x_k(n) = \big[x(k), x(k+1), ..., x(N-1), x(0), x(1), ...,x(k-1)\big] \rightarrow  e^{\frac{j2 \pi kn}{N}}X(n)$$

Now consider $k$ to be ***small*** say, $k=2$ but instead the obtained signal is:

$$x_2(n)=\big[x(2), x(3), ..., x(N-1), x(0), x(1)\big]$$

My question is about what happens when you change $k$ entries to something else, like this:

$$\tilde{x}_2(n)=\big[x(2), x(3), ..., x(N-1), y(0), y(1)\big]$$

where $y(0) \ne x(0)$ and $y(1) \ne x(1)$.

Thus given that $N$ is large and $k$ is small can we approximate DFT of new sequence w.r.t $X(n)$? Can we say that still the DFT of new signal will approximately the same as $e^{\frac{j2 \pi kn}{N}}X(n)$? If not can we have some error bound? You may further assume that:

$$\text{max}|y(0) - x(0)| = \text{max}|y(1)-x(1)| =c$$
where $c$ is some real valued constant.